# query github commits from a certain date using pygithub

Tags: python, github, pygithub

have the following code:

```py
from github import Github
...
g = github(token)
query = f'org:{org_name} author:{username} since=2021-10-19T00:00:00Z'
commits = g.search_commits(query, sort='author-date', order='desc')
```

If I have the "since" parameter there - I get 0 results.  If I take it out, I get hundreds - and that's the problem.  I'm doing some processing which can work this way so want to be incremental - ie cache the results and when I call it a few days later - only find the new commits since  the last time I read.

From the documentation, this should work - but ... it doesn't - what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer:
Try to use: `committer-date:<2023-01-01T01:00:00Z` with `>, >=, <, <=`

Long answer:
Basically, pygithub is forwarding the request to REST as mentioned in this link https://pygithub.readthedocs.io/en/stable/github.html?highlight=search_commits#github.MainClass.Github.search_commits

```
search_commits(query: str, sort: Opt[str] = NotSet, order: Opt[str] = NotSet, **qualifiers) → PaginatedList[Commit]

Calls:  
GET /search/commits

Parameters: 
query – string
sort – string (‘author-date’, ‘committer-date’)
order – string (‘asc’, ‘desc’)
qualifiers – keyword dict query qualifiers
Return type:    
PaginatedList of github.Commit.Commit
```

There is a `committer-date` you can use, such like `committer-date:<2023-01-01T01:00:00Z`. For the correct syntax, you can refer to https://docs.github.com/en/search-github/searching-on-github/searching-commits#search-by-authored-or-committed-date

```
Qualifier   Example
author-date:YYYY-MM-DD  author-date:<2016-01-01 matches commits authored before 2016-01-01.
committer-date:YYYY-MM-DD   committer-date:>2016-01-01 matches commits committed after 2016-01-01.
```

and more generic syntax here: https://docs.github.com/en/search-github/getting-started-with-searching-on-github/understanding-the-search-syntax#query-for-dates

You can also test your search syntax here

```
https://github.com/search?q=repo:neozhu/CleanArchitectureWithBlazorServer committer-date:<2023-01-01T01:00:00Z&type=commits
```